# jquery read child xml data

Tags: xml, ajax, jquery, xml-parsing

I'm wondering how to fix my script, I want to have an alert happen when you click the button yet it keep up with the changes happening to the xml on the same page.
I would of thought this script would of worked yet of course when I click the button nothing happens. Thought I'd see if I could get any input on it from someone a little more experienced.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

function get_info() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "xmldata/product.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        cache: false,
        complete: function(doc) {
            var product = $(doc.responseText).find("product").text() == 1;
            var name = product.next().children("name").text();
            var cost = product.next().children("cost").text();
            $("#xmlalert").click(function(){
                                alert(cost);
            })
        }
    });

}
setInterval(function() {
    get_info();
}, 5000);
});
```

The xml data is as shown:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<store>
   <product>1</product>
    <info>
        <name>Toy</name>
        <cost>1196</cost>
    </info>
</store>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Html code

```
<button class="button" id="1">One</button>
<button class="button" id="2">Two</button>
```

Change your javascript code like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      function get_info() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "xmldata/product.xml",
            dataType: "xml",
            cache: false,
            complete: function(doc) {
            $(".button").click(function(event){
                console.log($(this).attr('id'));
                var product = $(doc.responseText).find("product").eq($(this).attr('id')-1);
                var currentIndex=0;
                product.each(function(index){
                    var name = $(this).next().children("name").text();
                    var cost = $(this).next().children("cost").text();
                    alert(cost);    
                });
            });
        }
        });

        }
        setInterval(function() {
            get_info();
        }, 2000);
});
```

XML is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<store>
   <product>1</product>
    <info>
        <name>Toy</name>
        <cost>1196</cost>
    </info>
    <product>2</product>
    <info>
        <name>Toy 2</name>
        <cost>11962</cost>
    </info>

</store>
```

Comment: I don't want to ask too much, but is there a difference to what the xml file is called and whether it is in a subfolder? eg yours is cml.xml also by using find("product") that will only find one? is there a way to be more specific? as this xml will have more than one product, eg product 1, product 2 etc.

Comment: Ok I changed my answer for this.

Comment: Thank you, I actually figured this out right before I looked at your answer lol but it now alerts both costs at the same time were as I want it to only alert one. a seperate button is going to be for the second one.

Comment: But there will be problem if number of products are more, can say 50-100 then?

Comment: would json be easier and better for this?

Comment: @Keleko Also you can use `json` for this no need to handle xml. `Json` can a better option.

Comment: ya I was thinking that, Ive just never used json before. I like that script, it works quite well. thank you!